# Fetching the data through Graph API in the webpart using sharepoint framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-framework, typescript, jquery-ajax

**[I am trying to fetch my email messages through Graph API into the webpart in sharepoint framework]**

**In the webpart Not getting the details of my emails through Graph API**

**Error : Cannot read property of 'value' of null**

**This property of 'value' is defined in the function "this._renderEmailList(messages.value)"**

[image]

```
private _renderEmailList(messages: MicrosoftGraph.Message[]): void {
let html: string = '';
for (let index = 0; index < messages.length; index++) {
  html += `<p class="${styles.description}">Email ${index + 1} - ${escape(messages[index].subject)}</p>`;
}

// Add the emails to the placeholder
const listContainer: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#spListContainer');
listContainer.innerHTML = html;
```

}

**I have call that function in the render function**

```
public render(): void {
this.context.msGraphClientFactory
.getClient()
.then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
  // get information about the current user from the Microsoft Graph
  client
  .api('/me/messages')
  .top(5)
  .orderby("receivedDateTime desc")
  .get((error, messages: any, rawResponse?: any) => {

    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
    <div class="${ styles.myFirstGraphWebPart}">
    <div class="${ styles.container}">
      <div class="${ styles.row}">
        <div class="${ styles.column}">
          <span class="${ styles.title}">Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
          <p class="${ styles.subTitle}">Use Microsoft Graph in SharePoint Framework.</p>
          <div id="spListContainer" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>`;

    // List the latest emails based on what we got from the Graph
    this._renderEmailList(messages.value);

  });
});
```

}

Comment: Check if the variable 'messages' is null.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the full graph URL in your .api call
instead of .api("/me/messages") try .api("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages")